# node API, React on same EC2 Machine with different ports...why XHR failed error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to run Node and React on the same EC2 machine. I am getting the error XHR (178) failed error within the network tab of the developer tools. Oddly, the code works fine when I point the code to localhost and run Node on my laptop. I can also connect to the API via Postman and get data returned. I am thinking this has to do with security and permissions. I have a custom TCP inbound (port 3000) policy on EC2 and outbound open with 0.0.0.0/0.

Here is a code snippet.

```
axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `${API_URL}auth?email=${emailAddress}&password=${pword}`,
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(params),
    })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(`status ${result.status}`);
        if (result.status === 200) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data));
```

Also, my dev machine is Windows and my EC2 instance is Linux.

[image]

Does anyone know why I would be getting an XHR error? Can you point me in the right direction to help troubleshoot this issue?

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "arangojs": "^5.8.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.735.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dynamoose": "^2.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "googleapis": "^57.0.0",
    "helmet": "^3.23.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.20",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.8",
    "winston": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^8.1.1",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0"
  }
```

I have the following code on the node side. (localhost is replaced with my prod server path)

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,X-Auth-Token"
  );
  next();
});
```

Comment: Firstly, this would be a cross origin request since the origins (host + port) are different. So all rules of CORS would apply. You say it works locally - can you share what your package.json looks like? I suspect it proxies the request via your React server only, so it is not going to be cross-origin when you run it locally.

Comment: And this is where I learnt a lot about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the dependencies within the package.json I am using the cors package.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I made a mistake when I copied the URL of the AWS server. I did not include the http:// Thank you everyone that has thought about my problem.